# PHP Inserts only the first row

Tags: php

This PHP code only inserts the first row then returns an error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object.
Please Help.

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM shopcart WHERE UserID='$Useremail'";
    if(!$result = $db->query($sqlquery)) die ('Error getting Food Information ['.$db->connect_error.']');
    $result = $db->query($sqlquery);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        //echo $row['name'];
        $name= $row['name'];
        $productid = $row['ProductID'];
        $initialPrice = $row['InitialPrice'];
        $qty = $row['Quantity'];



        //insert into to ordereditems
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ordereditems (OrderID, ProductName, ProductID, Quantity, SalesPrice) 
        VALUES ('$orderid', '$name', '$productid','$qty','$initialPrice')";
        if(!$result = $db->query($sql)) die('There was an error Processing Order Again [' . $db->error . ']');

    }
```

Comment: You overwrite the `$result` variable with your insert query. Change it to `$result2` or something.

Comment: Inserting multiple records, and failing half way through... that's _exactly_ why people use DB's that support _transactions_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last line of the loop you overwrite the $result.

```
if(!$result = $db->query($sql)) die('There was an error Processing Order Again [' . $db->error . ']');
```

Should be:

```
if(!$result2 = $db->query($sql)) die('There was an error Processing Order Again [' . $db->error . ']');
```

Comment: an insert query just returns true if it successfully executed. There isn't supposed to be a comparison between select query and insert query.

Comment: Confused what he was attempting there.

Comment: removed downvote since you changed it. All he is doing is inserting on a loop using the records from the select query, and the if statement is there  in case the insert fails. No comparing going on :).

Answer (score 2):

You're trashing your `$result`:

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM shopcart WHERE UserID='$Useremail'";
    if(!$result = $db->query($sqlquery)) die ('Error getting Food Information ['.$db->connect_error.']');
    $result = $db->query($sqlquery);
    ^^^^^^--- your first query

    if(!$result = $db->query($sql)) die('There was an error Processing Order Again [' . $db->error . ']');
        ^^^^^^-kill the first query result, replace with new result
```

And note that you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and all of this code could trivially be replaced with a single `insert into ... select from ...` query.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert operation overwrites the `$result` variable. Change it to some other name like follows:

```
if(!$result2 = $db->query($sql)) die('There was an error Processing Order Again [' . $db->error . ']');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the initial result from SELECT query with the INSERT query.  Here's the fixed up code:

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM shopcart WHERE UserID='$Useremail'";
if(!$result = $db->query($sqlquery)) die ('Error getting Food Information ['.$db->connect_error.']');
//$result = $db->query($sqlquery);   // NOT NEEDED AS ALREADY EXECUTED AND ASSIGNED in the IF statement above

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    //echo $row['name'];
    $name= $row['name'];
    $productid = $row['ProductID'];
    $initialPrice = $row['InitialPrice'];
    $qty = $row['Quantity'];

    /*
    instead of assigning these variables manually you could also use:

    extract($row);

    this would convert name, ProductID, InitialPrice and Quantity to local variables $name, $ProductID, $InitialPrice and $Quantity. However make sure the db result does not contain key "result" as it would overwrite your $result object again :)
     */


    //insert into to ordereditems
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ordereditems (OrderID, ProductName, ProductID, Quantity, SalesPrice) 
    VALUES ('$orderid', '$name', '$productid','$qty','$initialPrice')";

    //if(!$result = $db->query($sql)) die('There was an error Processing Order Again [' . $db->error . ']');  // this is what overwrites $result and the next while check throws an error you just got
    if(!$db->query($sql)) die('There was an error Processing Order Again [' . $db->error . ']'); //here's the fixed version, $db->query for insert does not return an object but boolean (true/false) so no need to assign it to a $result variable
}
```